# Why does my custom code show warnings in the logs?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, modal-dialog, drupal-8

I have a site on Drupal 8.6 and Bootstrap 3.3.7

I created a custom module for the customer to accept the terms and conditions of the store when placing an order.

This displays a link to a checkbox before payment to display the terms and conditions in a modal window.

When I place an order here are the warnings in the logs (sorry my code is too long to be published here):

https://pastebin.com/1p5m1Ved

https://pastebin.com/XYbqDJje

https://pastebin.com/P93bStKh

Here is the file that created the problem :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_marketplace_terms_and_conditions\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "marketplace_terms_and_conditions",
 *   label = @Translation("Marketplace Terms and Conditions"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class MarketplaceTermsAndConditions extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $store_name = $this->order->getStore()->getName();
    $store_id = $this->order->getStoreId();
    $pane_form['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';
    $attributes = [
      'attributes' => [
        'class' => 'use-ajax',
        'data-dialog-type' => 'modal',
        'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
          'width' => auto
        ]),
      ],
    ];
    $link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(
      $this->t('terms and conditions of the store "@store_name"', ['@store_name' => $store_name]),
      Url::fromUri("internal:/store/$store_id/cgv", $attributes)
    )->toString();
    $pane_form['marketplace_terms_and_conditions'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept @terms.', ['@terms' => $link]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

What's wrong with my custom module and how to fix the problem ? Thank you

Comment: What is the contstant `auto` supposed to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this to

```
'width' => auto
```

this

```
'width' => 'auto'
```

It is assuming it to be a constant, as you can see from the errors, it has to be either a variable or a string.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved 2 warning but I still have this one https://pastebin.com/XYbqDJje

Comment: can i see the code of the page where you are getting this error, if i am not wrong, it may be due to you are trying to echo out an array, instead you'll have to pass the aray variable with its key.

Comment: It will be complicated because it is a page of the purchase tunnel. What do you want to see ? The source code?

Comment: I am not familiar with drupal, but the error "array to string conversion" is probably throwing due to an array being echo out. for example `<?php 
$ace = [
    0 => 'acd',
    1 => 'asd'
];
echo $ace; //Array to string conversion error

echo $ace[0].' '.$ace[1]; //no error
?>`

Comment: if your use print_r() in place of echo you might be able to single out the issue causing this, echo can only print strings.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to look at that